# How to compile assets js library in laravel-mix

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

How to compiling jquery library into laravel mix, I have copy library simple.money.format.js into resource/js and in webpack I compiling it

```
mix
   .js(['resources/js/simple.money.format.js',
      'resources/js/app.js'], 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

but when i call in in resource/js/app.js with code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#price').simpleMoneyFormat();
});
```

when I open console.log in browser showing 

`TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).simpleMoneyFormat is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

oh when i use

src="{{ asset('js/simple.money.format.js') }}" defer
in app.blade.php and in library simple.money.format in top of code in import jquery

import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

it is working